# Java Robot - Issue typing 'a' on mac

Tags: java, macos, awtrobot

So I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);
    robot.setAutoDelay(40);

    // This works fine
    robot.mouseMove(40, 130);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(200);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(200);

    // The 'a' is never inputted
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.delay(200);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
}
```

This code successfully moves the mouse to the location 40, 130 and clicks. I make sure to have a text editor open in this location so that it becomes focused.

The next bit of code is the issue. The keyPress/Release snippet works perfectly fine for other codes. (Like 100, corresponding to the number 4.) But for some reason the letter 'a' will not be printed into the text editor.

I have tried having the program continually loop and print a for ~5 seconds. After the programatic click it will not print 'a' in the text editor. If I click on the editor again myself during this time, the string of 'a's will then start to appear.

What is causing this behavior and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you run the exact same code with a different `VK_?` key event (i.e. `VK_B`), does it work?  Also, there seems to be some confusion as the ASCII code `100` is lower-case `d`, not the digit `4`.

Comment: Yes, the exact same code with VK_4 works properly. 
It seems as though VK_B does not work either though.

Comment: What if you alternate sending `VK_4` with `VK_A`, starting with `VK_4`?  Do you get the `4`s without the `A`s?  How about if you start with `VK_A`?  Please put some effort into experimenting with this.

Comment: I have been messing around with it for quite a while and all behavior that I come across does not seem to make sense. First off, `VK_4` followed by `VK_A` only prints `4`. I tried looping through 65 to 100 as keyPress/release values and I wind up with the output of `oty]0123` clearly there are many values missing. I have also tried increasing and decreasing the delay between release with no change in output. I also tried the other mouse 1 clicks in InputEvent and wound up with the same result. Same thing for double clicking

Comment: Provide an explicit list of the characters that work vs the ones that don't.

Comment: Your code works fine for me with every key. Is it possible that the focusing of your editor isn't working?

Comment: The fact that the Charakter is written when you focus the editor by yourself leads to this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i assumed in my comments i think you have a problem focusing the editor correctly.
You can try to use the Windows solution by doing `ALT`+`TAB` and then release it to select the editor.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);
robot.setAutoDelay(40);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);//on mac use VK_META
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);//on mac use VK_META
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.delay(200);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

Comment: This appears to be the issue. I had to change `VK_ALT` to `VK_META` for Mac alt+tab. Not sure why `BUTTON1_MASK` or `BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK` select the window improperly.

I believe the issue might be related to the fact that it is ran in the intellij _run_ area. Not sure though.